# «Sobre el nivel del mar» y «por encima del nivel del mar»

Tags: vocabulario, expresiones, sinónimos, abreviaturas

He recientemente descubierto que existen dos formas decir lo mismo.

Mi pregunta es: ¿son equivalentes exactos? La expresión «por encima del nivel del mar» me parece menos expandida. Además, no pude encontrar una abreviatura para ella, como «s.n.m.» para «sobre el nivel del mar».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las dos expresiones significan exactamente lo mismo. La preposición *[sobre](https://dle.rae.es/sobre)* significa, según el contexto, "encima de" (es decir, en contacto directo):

- Pon el lápiz sobre la mesa.

o "por encima de" (es decir, más arriba y sin contacto directo):

- La temperatura es de 2 grados sobre cero.

Refiriéndose al nivel del mar, "sobre el nivel del mar" se utiliza más que "por encima del nivel del mar", probablemente porque es más corto. Las abreviaturas pretenden ser universales, por tanto solo "sobre el nivel del mar" se ha abreviado a "s. n. m.".